# Copy A Formula Down From Every 8 Cells On Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this table that was copied from another website and unfortunately wasn't formatted as a table:

[unformated table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iC1Zs.png)

So I started to arrange the table with =transpose(). But I'm having to do it one column at a time.

[work-around](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuD47.png)

In one column I use: " =TRANSPOR(L6:L13) ", in the next one " =TRANSPOR(L14:L21) " etc.

Notice I'm jumping eight columns every time. So I wonder if there is a way that I could do this easier just by dragging down the formula.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
=FILTER(L1:L; MOD(ROW(L1:L); 8)=0)
```

yet, if you want to drag down your transpose use:

```
=TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1+(ROW(L1)-1)*8, 12)&":"&
                    ADDRESS(8+(ROW(L1)-1)*8, 12)))
```

Comment: That was super helpfull. Thank you very much!